# Adding two lights to existing light

Tags: lighting, switch

Would like to add two more lights to an existing light/switch setup. Would like to double check my approach. See below for existing vs proposed... purposely did not include ground.  Any and all feedback greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

**Existing**
[image: Existing]

**Proposed v1 (bad) and v2 (good - based on feedback from @bib and @Speedy Petey)**
[image]

Comment: Thanks for correcting. This site is meant to be a leaning opportunity for others. I would suggest you consider reinserting the original as well as the revised, so that others can understand what not to do as well as what to do. You can mark it as *First Draft* or *Rejected approach* or something to show you moved on.

Comment: Well done! Keep visiting us and contributing. You'll have plenty of rep in no time.

Comment: Also, don't be embarrassed about the mistake. The same cable rule is a little arcane and not intuitive to DIYers. In a recent reno in my house, I designed a brilliant multi cable circuit that saved cable, only to toss and turn in my sleep until I woke, knowing something was off and searched my books until I found the code rule and the reason. Redesigned to code.

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. If you believe your question is not useful or is no longer useful, it should be deleted instead of editing out all of the data that actually makes it a question. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a [non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content](/legal/terms-of-service/public#licensing) under the CC BY-SA 4.0 license. By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post, consider taking a look at: [How does deleting work](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221/295232)?

Answer (score 4):

The proposed wiring shown as Revision 1 in the original drawings is **not** code compliant. Under NEC 300.3(B), all wires for a given circuit must be in the same cable or raceway. In your example, the new lights get the hot lead from a single wire from the switch and the neutral from a separate cable or raceway from the old fixture.

Basically you need a balanced load in each cable or raceway (hot out/neutral back or hot out/switched hot back) to prevent the possibility of induction heating.

As @Speedy Petey suggests, a much simpler, and code compliant method, is to run a cable with a neutral and a switched hot from the existing fixture to the new fixtures.

**UPDATE:** Based on the added drawing in Revision 2, the proposed circuit is now code compliant. Also, as @Ben noted, any white wire used as a hot that is exposed in a box or fixture must be marked black or red with tape, paint or marker to show that it is hot.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very confusing way to wire this? What is your reasoning for wanting to do it this way?

Since you have to bring a wire from the existing light anyway, just bring both the switched hot and neutral right from the existing light to the new ones.

Comment: +1 I agree, and it is also against code. I added that and a reference to your correct approach in an answer.

Answer (score -1):

No problems there - although most would probably indicate the switched hot line as black/ or white/black.  Even if you have a white wire used like this. Always mark/label it black.  Some go as far as to wrap electric tape the length of it to hide the white. Better safe than sorry.